# How to configure the network settings in VirtualBox machine using the vboxmanage in console?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

After creating a new virtual machine, I select the adapter using the console:

```
vboxmanage modifyvm VMNAME --nic1 bridged --bridgeadapter1 eth0
```

How can i set the next settings of TCP/IPv4 using console:

- static ip,
- mask,
- default gateway,
- DNS servers ?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the next utility: vboxmanage guestcontrol.
And after type "netsh interface ip add address name="Local Area Connection" 192.168.1.20 255.255.255.0". Here is we execute command in cmd into windows vbox.

Comment: Thank you! it`s look like true